# sklearn random forest get training bias

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm working to build a regression model by sklearn. After training and testing the random forest model, I want to get training bias and test bias to evaluate the model. But unfortunately, I can only get testing bias by comparing the true labels and RandomForestRegressor.predict. I can't get training bias, since RandomForestRegressor.fit will return an object not a ndarray.

I know someimes we use score() to get R score to evaluate the model. But I really want to get the trainging bias of the random forest. What should I do? May I have to rewrite the function to get it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "training bias"; if you just want both training and test scores, you can `predict` on the training data just as well as on test data.

Comment: I want the mean absolute error(MAE) of the training process. As I know,  I can get the MAE of testing process. But I don't know how to get the MAE of traing. And from predict I can only get R square score, which isn't what I really want.

Comment: You can simply call `predict` on your trainning set and with its result calculate its MAE.

Comment: You mean I can use rfr.predict(x_train, y_train) to get the result? But I think it maybe not the real result of MAE cause I think I must use rfr.fit(x_train,y_train) first. After using rfr_fit(), the training set will be learned by the model, so it will provide wrong MAE. If it has something problem, please tell me.

Comment: @RaphaelSun It's true that the training score obtained that way is not an unbiased estimate of model performance, for the reason you state. But that's what a training score is. With random forest specifically, you could ask instead for the out-of-bag score from the training.